# Proxying an Apache Page to an Application

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I have an app running on `localhost:2000` whereas my site is on localhost.  I would like to point the directory `/projects/projectName` -> `localhost:2000`.  However, the problem comes when the app makes get/post requests.

For example, if a GET request is made at `/run`, the request shows the GET URL as `https://localhost/run` and returns a 404.  The two problems here are:

1. It redirects to port 443; and
2. the port 2000 is now lost on request.

Update: I tried turning off SSL but port 2000 is still lost on request.  Ideally I would like this to work with SSL.

These two issues may be one and the same but I am not sure.

To see how it is supposed to work, `http://stevenshi.me:2000` is the working application.  As you can see, the GET and POST requests go to the above url + `/foo`.

Here is my current apache conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]

    ServerAdmin admin@stevenshi.me
    ServerName stevenshi.me
    ServerAlias www.stevenshi.me
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin admin@stevenshi.me
            ServerName stevenshi.me:443
            ServerAlias www.stevenshi.me
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html

            SSLEngine on
            SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
            SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

            SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private.key
            SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem

            ProxyRequests on
            ProxyPreserveHost on
            <Proxy *>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Allow from localhost
            </Proxy>

            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteRule ^/projects/CS32Brewer/(.*)$ http://localhost:2000/$1 [

            #ProxyPass /projects/CS32Brewer/ http://localhost:2000/
            ProxyPassReverse /projects/CS32Brewer/ http://localhost:2000/

            #ProxyPass /projects/Maps http://locahost:2001
            #ProxyPassReverse /projects/Maps http://localhost:2001

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rewrite using mod_rewrite, or configure the application to create proper urls.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how OP would use `mod_rewrite`, or what "proper" URLs would look like?

Comment: In the apache config file, I have tried both proxy and rewrite methods; however, I am curious as to what these "proper" URL's might be.